# Python self.after() changes running order

Tags: python, tkinter

I am (still!) writing a Noughts and Crosses program using Tkinter in Python 3.
I wanted to implement a short pause between the player's move and the computer's move, so in the add_move_comp() method implemented self.after() function.
I expected this to pause the program for 1000ms then continue by 'drawing' on the computer's move.

However when I run my code, the program only recognises the computer's move the next move after, causing problems with identifying a 3-in-a-row.

I think this is due to line 62 running after 1000ms while the rest of the program continues running, but I don't know how to stop the whole program and continue running with line 62 after the pause.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from itertools import *
import random


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None): # init Window class
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # init Frame class
        self.master = master # allows us to refer to root as master
        self.rows = 3
        self.columns = 3
        self.guiGrid = [[None for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)] # use this for the computer's moves
        self.noText = StringVar(value = '')
        self.cross = StringVar(value = 'X')
        self.nought = StringVar(value = 'O')
        self.button_ij = None
        self.myMove = True

        self.create_window()
        self.add_buttons()

    def create_window(self):

        self.master.title('Tic Tac Toe')

        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        for i in range(0,3): # allows buttons to expand to frame size
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)


    def add_buttons(self):
        rows = 3
        columns = 3

        for i in range (rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                self.button_ij = Button(self, textvariable = self.noText, command = lambda i=i, j=j: self.add_move(i,j))
                self.guiGrid[i][j] = self.button_ij
                self.button_ij.grid(row = i,column = j, sticky =E+W+S+N)

    def add_move(self, i,j):
        # player's move
        while self.myMove:
            pressedButton = self.guiGrid[i][j]
            self.guiGrid[i][j].config(textvariable = self.cross)

            # computer's turn
            self.myMove = False

        while (self.myMove == False):
            self.add_move_comp()

    def add_move_comp(self):
            repeat = True
            while repeat:
                i = random.randint(0,0) # row - only allow O to be drawn on 1st row for testing purposes
                j = random.randint(0,2) # column
                testText = self.guiGrid[i][j].cget('text')
                if testText == '':
                    self.after(1000,lambda i = i, j = j :self.guiGrid[i][j].config(textvariable = self.nought)) # search up rules with returning values using lambda
                    print('Should plot O at row: ',i,' column: ',j)
                    print('TEXT ACTUALLY PLOTTED IS: ',self.guiGrid[i][j].cget('text'))
                    self.myMove = True
                    repeat = False
                    print(self.guiGrid[0][0].cget('text'), self.guiGrid[0][1].cget('text'), self.guiGrid[0][2].cget('text')+'THIS IS PRINTING')


root = Tk() # creating Tk instance

rootWidth = '500'
rootHeight = '500'
root.geometry(rootWidth+'x'+rootHeight)

ticTacToe = Window(root) # creating Window object with root as master

root.mainloop() # keeps program running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `self.after` imeadiately returns and starts the given function after passing trough a queque to prevent the actual Window from beeing unable to responde because there is some code running. A way to work around this is to create a BooleanVariable for validation and using `self.wait_variable` as follows:

```py
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial
from itertools import *
import random


class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master = None): # init Window class
        Frame.__init__(self, master) # init Frame class
        self.master = master # allows us to refer to root as master
        self.rows = 3
        self.columns = 3
        self.guiGrid = [[None for x in range(self.rows)] for y in range(self.columns)] # use this for the computer's moves
        self.noText = StringVar(value = '')
        self.cross = StringVar(value = 'X')
        self.nought = StringVar(value = 'O')
        self.button_ij = None
        self.myMove = True

        self.validationVar = BooleanVar(self)

        self.create_window()
        self.add_buttons()

    def create_window(self):

        self.master.title('Tic Tac Toe')

        self.pack(fill = BOTH, expand = 1)
        for i in range(0,3): # allows buttons to expand to frame size
            self.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight = 1)
            self.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight = 1)


    def add_buttons(self):
        rows = 3
        columns = 3

        for i in range (rows):
            for j in range(columns):
                self.button_ij = Button(self, textvariable = self.noText, command = lambda i=i, j=j: self.add_move(i,j))
                self.guiGrid[i][j] = self.button_ij
                self.button_ij.grid(row = i,column = j, sticky =E+W+S+N)

    def add_move(self, i,j):
        # player's move
        while self.myMove:
            pressedButton = self.guiGrid[i][j]
            self.guiGrid[i][j].config(textvariable = self.cross)

            # computer's turn
            self.myMove = False

        while (self.myMove == False):
            self.add_move_comp()

    def add_move_comp(self):
            repeat = True
            while repeat:
                i = random.randint(0,0) # row - only allow O to be drawn on 1st row for testing purposes
                j = random.randint(0,2) # column
                testText = self.guiGrid[i][j].cget('text')
                if testText == '':
                    self.after(1000, self.validationVar.set, True)
                    self.wait_variable(self.validationVar)
                    self.guiGrid[i][j].config(textvariable = self.nought) # search up rules with returning values using lambda
                    print('Should plot O at row: ',i,' column: ',j)
                    print('TEXT ACTUALLY PLOTTED IS: ',self.guiGrid[i][j].cget('text'))
                    self.myMove = True
                    repeat = False
                    print(self.guiGrid[0][0].cget('text'), self.guiGrid[0][1].cget('text'), self.guiGrid[0][2].cget('text')+'THIS IS PRINTING')


root = Tk() # creating Tk instance

rootWidth = '500'
rootHeight = '500'
root.geometry(rootWidth+'x'+rootHeight)

ticTacToe = Window(root) # creating Window object with root as master

root.mainloop() # keeps program running
```

Comment: _"... and starts the given function in a new thread"_ is incorrect. It definitely does _not_ run the code in a separate thread. Tkinter is single-threaded.

Comment: @Nummer_42O thank you so much for the code, you solved my problem of the program not recognising the computer's input during the current turn! Although, the pause for 1000ms no longer works. Is there a way to continue implementing this?

Comment: @BryanOakley, what would be the reason for my code not running in order?

Comment: @StudyAccount: you're explicitly telling it to run out of order by telling it to run something in the future. It still runs in the same thread, so "a(), after(1000, b), c()" is going to run a, c, and then a second later run b.

Comment: It seems like i forgot something. I updated my answer now.

Comment: @Bryan Oakely Oh I'm sorry then. I thought it works like that. Im curious to how it works then but I'll figure that out on my own. ^^

Comment: `after` simply puts the command on a queue. `mainloop` will execute the code on the queue when the time has expired.

Comment: This technique of waiting on a variable is good, I was mainly concerned about giving the wrong impression about threads.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I understood that you were only concerned about the thread thing, no worries. But nevertheless I missed out on putting wait_variable in the code example thats why I commented that.